# How to have a central place for data on the network and keep a copy locally on desktops?

Tags: windows, sync, home-networking, nas

Here's what we have at our home:

- Desktop with Win7
- Laptop with Win7
- Primary NAS with 1GB storage
- Secondary NAS with 2GB storage used for backup of primary NAS, desktop and laptop

I setup continuous backup from the desktop, laptop and primary NAS to the secondary NAS by using Oops Backup with a 1-hour schedule.

Works fine for backup however we would like to have all our data on the primary NAS with all the computers syncing to it transparently.

I know I can use a program that does 2-way (even 3-ways) syncing but I'm not sure if it's safe doing it.

Let's have some scenarios:

#### Scenario #1

I am editing a Word document on the laptop and when I save the document, it should be replicated to the NAS.

The desktop computer would see that the document has changed on the NAS and sync with it.

However if the document has changed on the desktop then we need a way to either block early or being warned of a conflict upon syncing.

From what I know, Word place some lock on the file (it even creates some temporary files)... Would it be sufficient to sync those files to the NAS and then to the other computer? Would that lock the file on the other computer?

#### Scenario #2

I am editing a TXT file on the desktop. Same as scenario #1 but no locking mechanism. What about this?

---

Basically it all comes down to locking out anyone else. I could use a source control program but I want something that is transparent.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**: Forgot to add that I want to be able to access files offline from the NAS (for example, when I take the laptop out of my home).

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/235257/local-cache-for-nas-or-network-folder

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with backup/syncing programs that constantly monitor what files you are editing, but I do know that SyncBackPro allows for backups and syncing across networks, and you can set it to run up to every second if you really wanted to.  If you want truly live backups, I would say use Google documents.

Comment: But with Google Documents I would not be able to view those offline nor is it transparent for use.

Comment: How do you expect to access your NAS offline besides directly plugging into it?  As for transparency, you can set SyncBackPro to run in the background without any popup.  2BrightSparks offers a free version of SyncBackPro, give it a shot.

Comment: I edited my question to specify I want offline access from the NAS (but still keep the syncing when I go back home). I'll look at SyncBackPro and see if it fits my needs.

Comment: What do you mean by offline access?  Do you mean you want to be able to access your NAS from outside your local network?  If you can't do that already, SyncBackPro won't be able to help you.  If by offline you mean access the files on your laptop's harddrive without being connected to the NAS? then yes you can with SBP.

Comment: By offline access I meant having a copy of files on the laptop. However, upon reconnecting the files are auto synced with the NAS.

Comment: Then yes, SBP will do that for you.  All it does is compare the files in the areas you have selected with the files already backed up on your NAS.  It then updates any modified file, and copies new files.  And if you set the run time to have it run every 5 minutes, then within 5 minutes of returning to your home network, it should backup any files that were changed while you were offline.

Comment: But will it handle the situation were the file were modified on the laptop and on the nas (from a previous sync with the desktop computer) ?

Comment: It allows you to define that scenario, I believe the default is to ask you.